# Range of Integral function

Tags: calculus

Let $$f'(x) = \frac{(192 x^{3})}{(2+\sin^4 (\pi x))}$$
$x \in R$ and $\displaystyle f(\frac{1}{2})=0$

If $\displaystyle m \le\int_\frac{1}{2}^{x} f(x) \,dx \le M$
then the possible values of $m$ and $M$ are

My steps are:

$f'(\frac{1}{2})=8$ and $f'(1)=96$

After this step I am not able to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Since $-1 \leq \sin(t) \leq 1$, assuming $x>0$, you could write

$$\frac{192 x^{3}}{(2+1)}\leq \frac{192 x^{3}}{(2+\sin^4 (\pi x))}\leq\frac{192 x^{3}}{(2+0)}$$ and this would help.

Comment: $$\frac{192 x^{3}}{(2+1)}\leq \frac{192 x^{3}}{(2+\sin^4 (\pi x))}\leq\frac{192 x^{3}}{(2+0)}$$           $$64 x^{3} \leq f'(x) \leq 96 x^{3}$$   $$16x^4+C1 \leq f(x) \leq 24x^4+C2$$ After this steps i am confused although f(1/2)=0